# How do I update the version of SaxonHE?

Tags: java, macos, saxon

I am running saxonhe9.jar from the command line (`java -jar saxonhe9.jar -versionmsg`) on MacOS El Capitan. No matter what .jar I download, the command returns "Saxon-HE 9.7.0.1J from Saxonica". I am not sure if this is an issue with just the version *message* or that version 9.7.0.1J is somehow hardwired to run when I call ANY saxon jarfile.

I've tried versions 9.4.0.9J, 9.7.0.15J, PE version 9.7.0.15J (trial version) and others. I have tried to clear my $PATH variables and change the $JAVA_HOME. I have uninstalled related packages (e.g. libxml2, libxslt) with Hombrew and pip (e.g. lxml). I'm all out of ideas. What could the issue be and how I could upgrade saxon?

Answer (score 1):

The $PATH and $JAVA_HOME variables are irrelevant here. The presence of absence of other software products like libxml2 or libxslt isn't going to affect things either.

Your command will run whatever is in the JAR file named saxonhe9.jar in your current working directory. Start by doing "ls -l" to see what is in that directory (if necessary, show us the output).

Note that the Saxonica-issued JAR files would be named "saxon9he.jar" or "saxon9pe.jar". Perhaps "saxonhe9.jar" is a typo, and refers to some older JAR which has been renamed for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Michael! I would have thought the same, but it's not working that way on my machine. I downloaded fresh copies of the HE9-7-0-15 and PE9-7-0-15, unzipped them and in each directory, ran the local jar. The resulting message (9.7.0.1) is the same in each case.
I've made a screenshot here: https://screencast.com/t/cFbC3iFs9u1 (If there's a better way to add images to comments on SO, pls let me know).

Comment: Thanks for showing the evidence. I am baffled, I can't think of any explanation for the observed behaviour. Do show us an "ls -l" to see if there are any permissions issues. And try running with the -cp option instead of -jar (just to see if it makes any difference). (Incidentally, -versionmsg doesn't mean what you think it does, but it has the desired effect. I would normally use -t).

Comment: The other thing I would suggest is searching your filestore for all instances of saxon9he.jar. Again, just to see if it shows up anything interesting.

Comment: ls -l results in:
`-rw-r--r--+ 1 arihershowitz staff 4769118 Feb  7 11:34 saxon9he.jar`
I did try to clear out any other saxon8he.jar instances, but found no smoking guns. What is the command for running with -cp instead of -jar work? I just get an error.

Comment: OK, well the file size 4769118 confirms that this is indeed Saxon 9.7.0.15. (9.7.0.1 would be 4661087). You could try using a full path name: `java -jar /Users/me/saxon9-7-0-15/saxon9he.jar`. The command with -cp is `java -cp  /Users/me/saxon9-7-0-15/saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -t`.